# $(...).dataTable is not a function using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, symfony, datatable

problem

- we are using angular & jquery.
- problem occurs when switching state say dashboard to mylogs.
- when i run url for mylogs then datatable is working with no error.
- then i click on dashboard it works no error.
- then i again click on mylogs link then angular js would not found jquery datatable function.
- therefore it throws error

angular code

```
  var sbAdmin2 = angular.module('sbAdmin2', ['ui.router','ngSanitize']);
  sbAdmin2.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/data');

    $stateProvider
         .state('Dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard/data',
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/weblogs_dev.php/dashboard/data'
        })
                 .state('My Logs', {
                            url: '/my_dt_test',
                            data: {
                                pageHeader: 'My Logs',
                                ncyBreadcrumbLabel: 'My Logs'
                            },
                            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                                label: 'My Logs'
                            },
                            views: {
                                "@": {
                                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/weblogs_dev.php/my_datatable_list1'

                                }
                            }
                        })
```

html

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('common/assets/libs/angular/source/angular.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}_{{ NOW }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/angular/source/modules/angular-ui-router.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}_{{ NOW }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/angular/source/modules/angular-sanitize.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}_{{ NOW }}"></script>


        <!-angular version 1.06------>
         <body>
         <div id="test" ui-view>
         {% body_block %}{%endblock%}
          </div>
           </body>
```

datatable is rendered in html view

```
          var dataTableVar_eserv_mylogs_new_table = $('#eserv_mylogs_new_table').dataTable({
            "columns": [{"sTitle":"Job_NO","sName":"logId"},{"sTitle":"customer","sName":"customer"}],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": dataTable_ajax_source_eserv_mylogs_new_table,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "asStripeClasses": null,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            //"colReorder": true,



            "paging": true,


            buttons: [{
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Custom Columns',
            className: 'btn btn-default pull-right extra_btn'
        }],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": (typeof PreloaderImagePath != 'undefined' ? '<img alt="Loading data... Please wait" src="' + PreloaderImagePath + '" />' : 'Processing...'),
                "sInfoFiltered": " (filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "First",
                    "sLast": "Last",
                    "sNext": "Next",
                    "sPrevious": "Previous"
                },
                "sZeroRecords": "No data available in table",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
                "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                "sLengthMenu": '<span class="desktop_inline_text">Show</span> _MENU_ <span class="desktop_inline_text">Rows</span>'
            },
```

- datatable we rendering through symfony2 library.

  ```
    on page reload its working then its stop working on swapping state
  ```

Error im getting

```
     TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
at eval (eval at globalEval (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:330:5), <anonymous>:18:84)
at Function.globalEval (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:330:5)
at jQuery.domManip (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:5411:16)
at jQuery.append (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:5194:15)
at jQuery.<anonymous> (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:5309:18)
at jQuery.access (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:3465:8)
at jQuery.html (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:5276:10)
at http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/angular/source/modules/angular-ui-router.js?v=1.6.10_1475157720:2791:18
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/angular/source/angular.js?v=1.6.10_1475157720:8525:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/angular/source/angular.js?v=1.6.10_1475157720:8034:11) <div id="wrapper" ui-view="" class="container ng-scope font_size_100">
```

i have tried to debug this problem
angular code snippet

```
        .state('My Logs', {



                        url: '/my_dt_test',

                         views: {



                            "@": {



                                templateUrl: function ($node) {

                                    console.log("testing");

                                    return root_url + 'my_datatable_list1';
                                }


                            }

                        }
                       })
```

- issue i found when i reload the url mydb_test then datatable is visible with no error.
- after when i change state i get value in console.log but doesn"t return any template file.
- it only display error dataTable is not a function i think jquery is doing some issue.

what we need

- we checked jquery loads first time at top order but when angular js works it would not able to call dataTable function of jquery.
- please advice in this issue.

Comment: Is the dataTable library loaded?

Comment: datatable is rendered through php

Comment: we have not used any lib of  datatble  we have symfony2 lib

Comment: `datatable()` is a jQuery plugin. If you don't include it, you cannot use it...

Comment: on page reload its working then its stop working on swapping state

Comment: whats your code to initialize data tables?

Comment: i have tried $('#eserv_mylogs_new_table').dataTable(); also on console but ist not working with angular js

Comment: sounds like you are reloading jQuery somehow and wiping out version that plugin originally attached itself to

Comment: i have updated the error that im getting please advice

Answer (score -1):

Add a `run block` and after every `state-change`, capture the `state-change-success` and reload the data tables.

```
var sbAdmin2 = angular.module('sbAdmin2', ['ui.router','ngSanitize']);
  sbAdmin2.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/data');

    $stateProvider
         .state('Dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard/data',
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/weblogs_dev.php/dashboard/data'
        })
                 .state('My Logs', {
                            url: '/my_dt_test',
                            data: {
                                pageHeader: 'My Logs',
                                ncyBreadcrumbLabel: 'My Logs'
                            },
                            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                                label: 'My Logs'
                            },
                            views: {
                                "@": {
                                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/weblogs_dev.php/my_datatable_list1'

                                }
                            }
                        })
    });

    sbAdmin2.run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){ 
        angular.element('#eserv_mylogs_new_table').dataTable();
      })
    })
```

Comment: hi sarvan  i try same thing but still same problem becuse once jquery loads its ok but work with angular its not calling datatable function that we get same error

Comment: does the $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess') getting called? `console.log` and check

Comment: This is not how to manage plugins or any dom code. The plugin should be initialized in a directive.

Comment: nopes it " s not calling rootscope i think it"s not finding jquery therefore while parsing html interpreter halts

Comment: who downvoted it?, I answered in a way that after every state change, the angularjs's `angular.element` is used to call the datatable instea of the jquery data table.

Comment: this is happening because on page refresh the jquery's datatable function is called and if the state changes, it is not being called, so I captured the state change event provided by ui-router to relaod the datatable, whats the matter ofdownvoting it?

Comment: hi sarvan i again check that when we changing state console.log prints that means  rootScope is working so where im wrong

Comment: Try this line console.log(angular.element('#eserv_mylogs_new_table')), are you getting this div?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124543/discussion-between-sravan-and-afeef).

Comment: no im only getting j…y.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#eserv_mylogs_new_table"} when state change and getting  html when relaoding datatable url : j…                                                                           y.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#eserv_mylogs_new_table"}context: documentselector: "#eserv_mylogs_new_table"__proto__: Object[0]
angularapp.js:164 [table#eserv_mylogs_new_table.datatable.table.table-striped.table-hover.table-bordered.dataTable.no-f…, context: document, selector: "#eserv_mylogs_new_table"]

Comment: im only getting table when we reload the page of datatable url